# How do I loop through Pandas column by individual and detect changes from another column?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm at a loss here not sure what to do I'm hoping someone can help.

I have a dataset with a personID, sportPlayed, and date. I need to be loop through each individual (personID) and return ONLY those that have played basketball, THEN played football. In the example below, only personID 1 and personID 3 would be returned. personID 4 played football, but they would not be returned since they played Soccer before and not Basketball.

Any idea how to approach this? Thanks!

```
personID     sportPlayed     date
1            Basketball      2020-01-01
1            Basketball      2020-01-02 
1            Football        2020-03-01
2            Baseball        2020-02-05
2            Baseball        2020-03-05
3            Basketball      2020-04-01
3            Football        2020-05-05
4            Soccer          2020-02-01
4            Football        2020-02-06
```

Comment: Is the ordering important? Do you want the match if the person has played Football then Basketball?

Comment: @AbhimanyuShekhawat Yes ordering is important. They have to play Basketball first, THEN Football.

Comment: And they can't play any sport in between?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the earliest date someone played Basketball, then check if that is before the last date they played Football. Then filter the Series and get the Index.

Someone with neither of those will not show up in the output, but as you only care about the players for which this is `True` that's okay.

```
s = (df[df['sportPlayed'].eq('Basketball')].groupby('personID').date.min()
      .lt(df[df['sportPlayed'].eq('Football')].groupby('personID').date.max()))

#personID
#1     True
#3     True
#4    False
#Name: date, dtype: bool

s[s].index
#Int64Index([1, 3], dtype='int64', name='personID')
```

Comment: Thanks for the resposne! Let's say that theoretically someone played Basketball, Football, then Soccer...so Football is in the middle. Will this query still return it?

Comment: @G.Nguyen Yes, it will, it just checks if there is basketball anywhere before the last football. If they need to be consecutive (i.e. Basketball, Soccer, Football doesn't count) let me know.

Comment: Thank you! I think this works except I didn't consider a condition that I see in my dataset. There is one individual that has done this order: Basketball, Football, Basketball. This person should qualify since they played basketball, then football, but this query is not picking it up. Any suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: @G.Nguyen That should still work because it would take the first basketball date and the last football date, so those would still compare properly. Are your dates `datetime`? try `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`